# Threading an endless while loop in Python 2

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm not sure why this does not work. The thread starts as soon as it is defined and seems to not be in an actual thread... Maybe I'm missing something.

```
import threading
import time

def endless_loop1():
    while True:
        print('EndlessLoop1:'+str(time.time()))
        time.sleep(2)

def endless_loop2():
    while True:
        print('EndlessLoop2:'+str(time.time()))
        time.sleep(1)

print('Here1')
t1 = threading.Thread(name='t1', target=endless_loop1(), daemon=True)
print('Here2')
t2 = threading.Thread(name='t2', target=endless_loop2(), daemon=True)
print('Here3')
t1.start()
print('Here4')
t2.start()
```

Outputs:

```
Here1
EndlessLoop1:1446675282.8
EndlessLoop1:1446675284.8
EndlessLoop1:1446675286.81
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give `target=` a *callable object*.

```
target=endless_loop1()
```

Here you're *actually calling* `endless_loop1()`, so it gets executed in your main thread right away. What you want to do is:

```
target=endless_loop1
```

which passes your `Thread` the function object so it can call it itself.

Also, `daemon` isn't actually an init parameter, you need to set it separately before calling `start`:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(name='t1', target=endless_loop1)
t1.daemon = True
```

Comment: So if I wanted to pass an "argument" to the thread before execution I would have to declare the variable beforehand  `endless_loop1.args = x ` then `target=endless_loop1` instead of `target=endless_loop1(x)`?

Comment: @s4w3d0ff no, the `Thread` constructor has an `args` parameter for that, so you can just say: `Thread(name='t1', target=endless_loop1, args=(x,))`